# SQL- How to find average of a column using values only in last N rows

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I have a data table which looks like this.

```
datestamp   timestamp   vix    
2015-05-13   16:30:00   18.0     
2015-05-14   16:30:00   19.2
2015-05-15   16:30:00   18.5
2015-05-18   16:30:00   17.5
2015-05-19   16:30:00   17.0
```

I want to get the average(avg()) of the column vix for last 3 days. I know how to get last 3 rows using query like this

```
select vix from my_table order by date desc limit 3
```

How can i further compute average of last 3 days? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: store date and time as a single entity

Comment: arth's response is much better than jarlh.  using a derived table for a simple query is far from optimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a derived table:

```
select avg(dt.vix)
from
(select vix from my_table order by date desc limit 3) dt
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends if you want the last 3 days or the last 3 records..

For strictly the last three days:

```
SELECT AVG(t.vix)
  FROM table t
 WHERE t.datestamp > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

is preferable, otherwise go for Jarlh's answer